# How to solve this error message?"is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision \ may be lost."

Tags: warning-messages

[image]

How to solve this error message?
I don't know how to set precision.

if I in this case would not have this error

k10 = {};
Do[If[Positive[Det[Table[(-0.15 + x*1.499*10^(-6))^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]],AppendTo[k10, x]], {x, 100}];
k10

but in this case

k10 = {};
Do[If[Positive[Det[Table[(-0.15 + x*1.499*10^(-6))^(i + j), {i, 1, 19}, {j, 1, 19}]]], AppendTo[k10, x]], {x, 100}];
k10

It would go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you make your numbers exact, then no problem. And it is better to use `Sow` and `Reap` to build a list on the fly rather than `Append`

```
ClearAll[tbl, x];
a = SetPrecision[1.49910^(-6), Infinity];
b = SetPrecision[-0.15, Infinity];
tbl[x_] := Table[(b + x *a)^(i + j), {i, 1, 19}, {j, 1, 19}];
res =Last@Reap[
   Do[ If[ Positive[Det[tbl[x]]], Sow[x]],
    {x, 100}
    ]
   ];
```

But your result is empty. All determinants zero. To see this

```
ClearAll[tbl, x];
a = SetPrecision[1.49910^(-6), Infinity];
b = SetPrecision[-0.15, Infinity];
tbl[x_] := Table[(b + x *a)^(i + j), {i, 1, 19}, {j, 1, 19}];
res = First@Last@Reap[
     Do[ 
      Sow[{x, Det[tbl[x]]}],
      {x, 10}
      ]
     ];
res // MatrixForm
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the information.
But x=-0.1253, the det[]=3.06669*10^-205, which is not zero.
Why the final table is empty?

Answer (score 1):

You have asked several questions of this form.  In all cases the Table results are exactly zero.  Evaluating

```
res = Table[{x, Det[Table[(-a + x*b)^(i + j), {i, 1, 19}, {j, 1, 19}]]}, {x, 1,  100}]
```

gives all zeroes, indicating that the result is true for any numerical or symbolic values for a and b.

The error message which you obtained is indicating that your calculation is not being done with exact arithmetic, and tiny inexact numbers are being produced.  In such cases it is wise to consider whether such tiny (inexact) numbers represent zero.

Comment: Thank you for the support.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Thank you
For this problem, which is "K=10" in this image（Horizontal axis is x-value）, around x=-0.15 the det[] exactly is 0.
But I test other x-value, the det[] is also zero.

Comment: Please use "Answer" to answer a question, not to post a comment

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the information.